# How to refactor, fix and optimize this character replacement function in java

Tags: java, string, optimization, refactoring, char

While tuning the application, I found this routine that strips XML string of CDATA tags and replaces certain characters with character references so these could be displayed in a HTML page.

The routine is less than perfect; it will leave trailing space and will break with StringOutOfBounds exception if there is something wrong with the XML.

I have created a few unit tests when I started working on the routing, but the present functionality can be improved, so these serve more of a reference.

The routine needs refactoring for sanity reasons. But, the real reason I need to fix this routine is to improve a performance. It has become a serious performance bottleneck in the application.

```
package engine;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class StringFunctionsTest extends TestCase {

    public void testEscapeXMLSimple(){
        final String simple = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John & Smith</sender>]]></SvcRsData></xml> ";      
        final String expected = "<xml><SvcRsData>a&#60;sender&#62;John &#38; Smith&#60;/sender&#62;</SvcRsData></xml> ";
        String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(simple);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
    }

    public void testEscapeXMLCDATAInsideCDATA(){
        final String stringWithCDATAInsideCDATA = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John <![CDATA[Inner & CD ]]>& Smith</sender>]]></SvcRsData></xml> ";       
        final String expected = "<xml><SvcRsData>a&#60;sender&#62;John &#60;![CDATA[Inner &#38; CD & Smith</sender>]]></SvcRsData></xml> ";
        String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(stringWithCDATAInsideCDATA);      
        Assert.assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
    }

    public void testEscapeXMLCDATAWithoutClosingTag(){      
        final String stringWithCDATAWithoutClosingTag = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John & Smith</sender></SvcRsData></xml> ";
        try{
            String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(stringWithCDATAWithoutClosingTag);
        }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){
            Assert.assertNotNull(exception);
        }   
    }

    public void testEscapeXMLCDATAWithTwoCDATAClosingTags(){        
        final String stringWithCDATAWithTwoClosingTags = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John Inner & CD ]]>& Smith</sender>]]>bcd & efg</SvcRsData></xml> ";        
        final String expectedAfterSecondClosingTagNotEscaped = "<xml><SvcRsData>a&#60;sender&#62;John Inner &#38; CD & Smith</sender>]]>bcd & efg</SvcRsData></xml> ";
        String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(stringWithCDATAWithTwoClosingTags);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.equals(expectedAfterSecondClosingTagNotEscaped));
    }

    public void testEscapeXMLSimpleTwoCDATA(){
        final String stringWithTwoCDATA = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John & Smith</sender>]]>abc<sometag>xyz</sometag><sometag2><![CDATA[<recipient>Gorge & Doe</recipient>]]></sometag2></SvcRsData></xml> ";      
        final String expected = "<xml><SvcRsData>a&#60;sender&#62;John &#38; Smith&#60;/sender&#62;abc<sometag>xyz</sometag><sometag2>&#60;recipient&#62;Gorge &#38; Doe&#60;/recipient&#62;</sometag2></SvcRsData></xml> ";
        String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(stringWithTwoCDATA);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
    }

    public void testEscapeXMLOverlappingCDATA(){
        final String stringWithTwoCDATA = "<xml><SvcRsData>a<![CDATA[<sender>John & <![CDATA[Smith</sender>]]>abc<sometag>xyz</sometag><sometag2><recipient>Gorge & Doe</recipient>]]></sometag2></SvcRsData></xml> ";      
        final String expectedMess = "<xml><SvcRsData>a&#60;sender&#62;John &#38; &#60;![CDATA[Smith&#60;/sender&#62;abc<sometag>xyz</sometag><sometag2><recipient>Gorge & Doe</recipient>]]></sometag2></SvcRsData></xml> ";
        String result = StringFunctions.escapeXML(stringWithTwoCDATA);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.equals(expectedMess));
    }

}
```

---

This is the function:

```
package engine;

public class StringFunctions {

    public static String escapeXML(String s) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        int stringSize = 0;
        int posIniData = 0, posFinData = 0, posIniCData = 0, posFinCData = 0;
        String stringPreData = "", stringRsData = "", stringPosData = "", stringCData = "", stringPreCData = "", stringTempRsData = "";
        String stringNewRsData = "", stringPosCData = "", stringNewCData = "";
        short caracter;

        stringSize = s.length();
        posIniData = s.indexOf("<SvcRsData>");
        if (posIniData > 0) {
            posIniData = posIniData + 11;
            posFinData = s.indexOf("</SvcRsData>");
            stringPreData = s.substring(0, posIniData);
            stringRsData = s.substring(posIniData, posFinData);
            stringPosData = s.substring(posFinData, stringSize);
            stringTempRsData = stringRsData;
            posIniCData = stringRsData.indexOf("<![CDATA[");
            if (posIniCData > 0) {
                while (posIniCData > 0) {
                    posIniCData = posIniCData + 9;
                    posFinCData = stringTempRsData.indexOf("]]>");
                    stringPreCData = stringTempRsData.substring(0,
                            posIniCData - 9);
                    stringCData = stringTempRsData.substring(posIniCData,
                            posFinCData);
                    stringPosCData = stringTempRsData.substring(
                            posFinCData + 3, stringTempRsData.length());

                    stringNewCData = replaceCharacter(stringCData);
                    stringTempRsData = stringTempRsData.substring(
                            posFinCData + 3, stringTempRsData.length());
                    stringNewRsData = stringNewRsData + stringPreCData
                            + stringNewCData;
                    posIniCData = stringTempRsData.indexOf("<![CDATA[");
                }
            } else {
                stringNewRsData = stringRsData;
            }
            stringNewRsData = stringNewRsData + stringPosCData;
            s = stringPreData + stringNewRsData + stringPosData;
            stringSize = s.length();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++) {
            caracter = (short) s.charAt(i);
            if (caracter > 128) {
                result.append("&#");
                result.append(caracter);
                result.append(';');
            } else {
                result.append((char) caracter);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();

    }

    private static String replaceCharacter(String s) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        int stringSize = s.length();
        short caracter;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++) {

            caracter = (short) s.charAt(i);
            if (caracter > 128 || caracter == 34 || caracter == 38
                    || caracter == 60 || caracter == 62) {
                result.append("&#");
                result.append(caracter);
                result.append(';');
            } else {
                result.append((char) caracter);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [StringEscapeUtils Class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/). It contains an [`escapeXML`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 2):

it looks to me that you are doing something that has already been done before, probably in apache commons.

Your function is so convoluted that im not sure if you are really 'escapingXML' or something something more. if all you are doing is escaping xml, then you should google for a better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons. This has functions to escape/unescape XML/HTML reliably.